# Como pegar o HostName do cliente utilizando c#?

Tags: c#, dns, host

Preciso guardar em que maquina o usuário realizou determinada ação, para isso eu estava utilizando o seguinte trecho:

```
string maquina = Dns.GetHostName();
```

Porém, mal sabia eu que isso me retorna o HostName do servidor. Como pegar o HostName do cliente?

Comment: Qual tipo de projeto você está utilizando?

Comment: @Randrade ASP.NET Web Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o comando abaixo:

```
Request.UserHostName
```

Mas em alguns casos não funciona. Não sei se por causa do navegador ou da infraestrutura de rede (ex. Load balance)